# Alternative ways of setting full sized background image for mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I am making media query for mobile website and i am trying to set background to image:

```
body {
background: url("../images/back1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

This doesn't work for mobile phones.As i understand i can not use fixed for mobile browsers.My question what other ways are there for making background image without stretching it too much or making it blurry.Thank you for your time

Comment: What do you mean by "mobile browsers"? There are many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a child container for the body.

```css
    body {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 700px;
      }
      body div {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        background: url("https://placehold.it/480x720") no-repeat center center;
        webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
      }
```

```html
<body>
  <div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Note: This may be an inefficient way to get the result. Adding too many DOM elements will increase computations done by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the core issue is that you don't have this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will enable "responsiveness" in mobile browsers.